# DCRoundSwitch as Accessory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating an ios app where I want to use a switch as the accessory for a tableview.  I've found the following sample of how to use a UISwitch as the accessory: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html (see "Responding to Selections" section).

What I'd like to do is to use a DCRoundSwitch (https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch) instead of a UISwitch so I can customize the text.  But when I create the accessory in the way that is suggested by the sample code, I just get the round knob, I don't get the whole switch.  The code I'm using to add the accessory is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"PersonCell";

    MyPerson *person = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    DCRoundSwitch *switchObj = [[DCRoundSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 1.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    switchObj.onText = @"in";
    switchObj.offText = @"out";

    [switchObj addTarget:self action:@selector(personIn:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
    cell.accessoryView = switchObj;

    [[cell textLabel] setText:person.name];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:person.label];
    return cell;
}
```

What can I do to make the DCRoundSwitch work as a TableView accessory?

Thanks!

Comment: where is the code that actually assigns the switch to the accessory view? As in `cell.accessoryView = switchObj;`

Comment: ack, copy/paste error.  Updated code to include that.  Hopefully it's consistent - I've been playing with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you width is just to narrow -- try something like 60 or 70 for the width (the default width for a UISwitch in the storyboard is 79).

Comment: Hmmm.  That makes the circle bigger, but doesn't make any of the rest of the slider appear.  I'm wondering if it's got something to do with using it as an accessory - a normal accessory (check mark, >, etc) is very narrow - wonder if I could force the accessory to be wider if that would allow for the slider part to appear.

Comment: @nojo, I don't know why you're seeing that result -- I've used it as an accessory view, using nearly identical code to what you have, and it worked fine (with a size of 65,22).